# How to get ArrayList in JSP files using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

```
@RequestMapping("/get")
    public ModelAndView add()
    //public void Connector()
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml");
        EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao) ctx.getBean("edao");
        List<Employee> list=dao.getAllEmployees();

        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();


        mv.setViewName("display1.jsp");
        mv.addObject("emp", list);
        return mv;
        //System.out.println(dao.getAuth());

    }
```

I am trying to display the list to jsp using jstl with modelAndView object I am getting the list from database and but not able to print it on jsp.
please help me
thankyou

Comment: Can you post your jsp code here with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to print List in jsp. `em` is a item of `emp` list and `forEach` just like JAVA for loop of List. Here in `li` i have put `em.name` and `em.something` to be replaced by your `Employee` class property you want to print.

```
<c:forEach items="${emp}" var="em">
        <li>${em.name}</li>
        <li>${em.something}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

Don't forget to add tag lib in your jsp file

`<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

Comment: yeah i have done the same but i ma not able to get it

Comment: with one variable its working but but with collection or list its not working

Comment: thanks i got it i just had to add <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>